# Regex: Find duplicate tags (with or without the same content)

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have 1000 html pages, and I want to find all the pages that has a duplicate tags ("og:title"), such as:

`<meta property="og:title" content="BLAH BLAH" />`

etc...

etc...

`<meta property="og:title" content="Elvis Presley" />`

can anyone help with a nice regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `(property="og:title)[\s\S]*\1"`
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Search in document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(property="og:title")   : group 1, must contain literally property="og:title"
[\s\S]*                 : 0 or more any character (i.e. space OR not space)
\1                      : reference to group 1, must contain literally property="og:title"
```